# DataCardValue PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, microsoft365

Hello everyone can someone help me with how you can ensure that with these DataCardValue's you can ensure that once the Department has chosen Support or Development, that Windows Laptop (Finance Only) cannot be chosen in the Hardware DataCardValue, but it must be available in the list for Sales. How should I fix this? Can someone help me?

In addition, an 'Other' field must be implemented in the Hardware list, so you can fill in custom text. How do I add this? I'm using an Sharepoint list.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put a conditional If() function on the items property of the hardware list. It would then be followed by a filter function that will just return the proper values based off your conditional statement (ex. `If(Dropdown1.selected = "support" || Dropdown1.selected = "development", Filter(Dropdown2)`... I think you get the concept.